# Postgresql single-query to combine tables while replacing foreign keys with last names

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, dbeaver

I'm working with Postgresql and I am hoping to achieve this task with a single sql query. Generally, this would not be an issue, however, my tables are structured where I have multiple foreign key references to the same table on a per row basis:

Two tables in question:

**People_Table:**

- person_id (pk)
- firstName (text)
- lastName  (text)
- age (int)
- years_of_employment (float)
- sal (int)
- position (fk to different table not provided)

**Statistics_Table**

- stat_id
- supervisor_id (fk to people)
- secretary_id  (fk to people)
- research_assistant (fk to people)
- department_id (fk to different table not listed)

I need to query the statistics table and:

- get salaries for our 3 people and
- get years of service for all 3
- sum all their years and salaries
- and return these details from my query in a specific format:

people fkey references replaced with last_name, department_id with department_name, and insert each employees years and salary and add two columns for total_salary and cumulative_years

```
deptName|supName|supSal|supYears|secName|secSal|secYears|rdName|rdSal|rdYears|totalSal|totalYears
```

I can do this for each person individually, but it takes me three separate queries. I'm hoping there is a way to do it in one query so that the results of this one query is as follows (grouped by department and ordered by sum of all salaries in desc limit 20:

Here is an example of one of my queries: This query returns

```
select
    SUPERQUERY.salary, SUPERQUERY.lastName, SUPERQUERY.years, SUPERQUERY.dept from
    (
        select p.last_name as lastName, p.salary as salary, p.years_of_employment as years,
                       d.department_name as dept
        from public."Statistics" as s
        join public."People" as p on s.supervisor_id = p.person_id 
                join public."Departments" a d on d.department_id = s.department_id
        order by s.department desc limit 20
    ) as SUPERQUERY;
```

Example of what this result looks like:

```
DepartmentName|Supervisor|Sup_sal|years
Fake Dept.    |Smith     |180,000| 17
```

If I can do this for each "people" in the stat table but in one query rather than 3, that would be ideal. My thought is nesting these subqueries using CASES but not sure how or if I can. I'm somewhat new to SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will assist with your issues, but there are certain expectations upon you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and to review [ask]. Then update your question to include actual table definitions (ddl) (for ALL tables involved), sample data and the expected results of that data. All as formatted text (see [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or much better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) - **No Images**.

Comment: You can do all this is a single  query. You will probably want `left join` as (I assume) there is no requirement that every person has a secretary and a
research_assistant for example. You are on the right track but you seem to think you can have only a single join for a given table - not true. You can join the same table multiple times, just insure each a distinct alias. So `from statistics_table st left join persons sup ... left join persons sec ... left join persons ra ... join department ...)` is a valid structure.

Comment: A suggestion: never store `age` or `years_of_employment` or any duration. That quickly becomes a maintenance nightmare. Instead store `dates` (i.e. `birth_date`, `hire_date`) then let Postgres calculate the duration. See [AGE](https://www.rockdata.net/tutorial/function-age/) function and [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) data type.

Comment: Thank you @Belayer… I will give this a shot when I get the time tomorrow. This was merely an example of what I’m trying to do with different tables and different data that I’m not allowed to share… but I appreciate the tip as I probably would have made that mistake in the future and then would have to go through the dreaded migrations 

Answer (score 0):

Try below>> By joining the `Statistics_Table` with the `People_Table` three times, each for a different role (`supervisor, secretary, research assistant`), and also with the Departments table, I aggregated key details like salaries and years of employment for each role.

```
SELECT
    d.department_name AS deptName,
    sup.last_name AS supName,
    sup.sal AS supSal,
    sup.years_of_employment AS supYears,
    sec.last_name AS secName,
    sec.sal AS secSal,
    sec.years_of_employment AS secYears,
    ra.last_name AS rdName,
    ra.sal AS rdSal,
    ra.years_of_employment AS rdYears,
    (sup.sal + sec.sal + ra.sal) AS totalSal,
    (sup.years_of_employment + sec.years_of_employment + ra.years_of_employment) AS totalYears
FROM
    Statistics_Table st
JOIN
    People_Table sup ON st.supervisor_id = sup.person_id
JOIN
    People_Table sec ON st.secretary_id = sec.person_id
JOIN
    People_Table ra ON st.research_assistant = ra.person_id
JOIN
    Departments d ON st.department_id = d.department_id
ORDER BY
    (sup.sal + sec.sal + ra.sal) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```